Do Django ListViews automatically generate templates for Django models?

That’s all the Python code we need to write. We still need to write a template, however. We could explicitly tell the view which template to use by adding a template_name attribute to the view, but in the absence of an explicit template Django will infer one from the object’s name. In this case, the inferred template will be "books/publisher_list.html" – the “books” part comes from the name of the app that defines the model, while the “publisher” bit is the lowercased version of the model’s name.

This comes from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/
after the PublisherListView is displayed and the URL is configured. I have several questions:
By changing the model equal to publisher, I understand that this view looks at a template books/publisher_list. Is this template already created by Django if it's a Django model, with default code/logic to handle the display of multiple items of the given model? Or does it just look for a template with the name books/publisher_list in the namespaced templates directory?
Just to be clear, does changing the model attribute for a ListView query all instances of that model and put them into object_list, which is the context necessary for rendering the template (assuming we don't have a context_object_name attribute)?
I appreciate the help.

First to answer your question about the ListView class, then yes this view only looks for by default for "appname/modelname_list.html" like for example books/publisher_list.html since book is the app name and publisher is a model of the app defined in models.py. It doesn't create the template for you and you have to do it and populate it with whatever you want, though you do have access in the template context to the object_list variable to loop through it for example and print the names of the publishers in this case, though there is another variable too which is publisher_list that is the same as object_list and was set because you provided a value to the model like model = Publisher, otherwise this variable won't be defined (since it's not necessary to define model variable for a view that inherits from ListView), but clearly its name is far more better and explains more what the variable represents, though if you want and like you mentioned you can provide you own name using context_object_name, So in conclusion yes the ListView if provided the model attribute, it gets all records of that model in the database and sets that in the template context to object_list and modelname_list (use whatever variable name you want in your template, both are accessible), then either looks for the default name value of the template like explained above or if template_name attribute is provided then it looks for that specific template like for example in this case template_name = books/myPublishers.html.

Now Secondly you might be wondering where can I find all this details and explanations for the class based views for next time or for further customization, then in this case you have to reference the django documentation which I'll give an example in this case for the ListView class right here, after you consult this link you see the class definition, some examples down and name of methods of this class, but most importantly the ancestors section which is really important and means from which classes the ListView class is inheriting from, and click on any one of them to see too what are those classes and most importantly what are their attributes so you can understand them and modify them for you own use, so for example if you choose TemplateResponseMixing link which is an ancestor of ListView (a Parent Class in OOP terms if you're familiar with that), then its attributes section shows the template_name variable, what it does and which you can use in your own view later to override the name of the template used like the example above. Finally sorry for the very long response and hope it helps.
